# Check length of field is greater than zero

Tags: php, if-statement

In the below snippet, a data packet has been created for an online form but if one of the fields is intentionally left blank, it throws an error. How can I revise this so that say if the string length is greater than 0, create the data packet, if not, just don't set it or leave it undefined?

```
$formData = $_POST['form'];//form post value

 // Create vendor packet
    $oVendor = new stdClass();
    $oVendor->office_name = $formData['vendor_info'][1]['vendor_bus'];
    $oVendor->first_name = $formData['vendor_info'][1]['vendor_first'];
    $oVendor->middle_name = $formData['vendor_info'][1]['vendor_middle'];
    $oVendor->last_name = $formData['vendor_info'][1]['vendor_last'];

    $oVendor->business_address = array(
        'street' => $formData['vendor_address'][1]['vendor_street'],
        'city' => $formData['vendor_address'][1]['vendor_city'],
        'state' => $formData['vendor_address'][1]['vendor_state'],
        'zip' => $formData['vendor_address'][1]['vendor_zip'],
        'is_primary' => $formData['vendor_address'][1]['checkbox_primary']);

    $oVendor->mailing_address = array(
        'street' => $formData['vendor_mail'][1]['vendor_street'],
        'city' => $formData['vendor_mail'][1]['vendor_city'],
        'state' => $formData['vendor_mail'][1]['vendor_state'],
        'zip' => $formData['vendor_mail'][1]['vendor_zip'],
        'is_primary' => $formData['vendor_mail'][1]['checkbox_primary']);

        $emails = array();
    $i = 1;
    foreach($formData['vendor_emails'] as $email)
        $emails[$i++] = $email['vendor_email'];

    $oVendor->emails = $emails;
```

Comment: isset(), empty() strlen() ?

Comment: pre-populate the Form fields with N/A or Not available or undefined. Unless the User sets a value for the form filed, the value will not be changed.

Comment: @John guess i was referring to strlen()